# Ho to make .htacess redirect and keep full url path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi i would like ask you about .htacess 301 redirect:

I have many dynamic urls with paths for example like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/post1.html
http://www.domain.com/post2.html
```

and i need to redirect it to the same url but with little bit different domain (without WWW):

```
http://domain.com/post1.html
http://domain.com/post2.html
```

I have done like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirect works, but my normal urls becomes urls with ID's like:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?id=931
```

not like it should be:

```
http://domain.com/post1.html
```

Any ideas or helo are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: put all .htaccess content here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some other rewrite rules happening here obviously, but with what you've given us, you could try adding this *before* your rules in order to get it to stop processing an URL which has been rewritten as such:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  id=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
```

Comment: Yes, you was right it was set other rules before, i just moved up my rules and everything went fine!